# store for loop values in variable in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I am using a for loop obtain a set of p-values using the "pbinom" function. The values 1:5 simply refer to the number of observed counts, 21, refers to the sample size, and 0.05 refers to the probability of success:

```
for ( i in 1:5) {
print (1 - pbinom(i, 21, 0.05))
}

[1] 0.2830282
[1] 0.08491751
[1] 0.01888063
[1] 0.00324032
[1] 0.0004415266
```

This code works fine, but it just outputs the values the values on the command prompt as above.

My question is, how can I store the output in a variable?

I tried

```
output<-for ( i in 1:5) {
print (1 - pbinom(i, 21, 0.05))
}
```

But when I entered "output", I received "NULL" in response.

Any help would be appreciated,
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use a `for` loop at all for this. `pbinom` is vectorized. Just do

```
(output <- 1 - pbinom(1:5, 21, 0.05))
## [1] 0.2830281552 0.0849175139 0.0188806334 0.0032403196 0.0004415266
```

In a worst case scenario you can use `sapply` instead which outputs the vector by default, something like

```
(output <- 1 - sapply(1:5, pbinom, 21, 0.05))
## [1] 0.2830281552 0.0849175139 0.0188806334 0.0032403196 0.0004415266
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, David. I just have one follow up question: If had multiple probabilities of success, say 0.05 and 0.02. How can I get the same output in your answer, but with a vector of p-values for each success probability (separated by row), such that row one represents the pvalues for 0.05 and row two represents the pvalues from 0.02?

Comment: `1 - pbinom(1:2, 21, c(0.02, 0.05))`?

Comment: I tried this, but only outputs the pvalues for the first value in the vector, so all pvalues for 0.02

Comment: Nope. Compare to `1 - pbinom(1:2, 21, 0.05)` and
`1 - pbinom(1:2, 21, 0.02)` and then find the difference.

Comment: So after entering all the above commands, I see that `1 - pbinom(1:2, 21, c(0.02, 0.05))`, I get `[1] 0.06534884 0.08491751`, which corresponds to the outputs obtained by: `1 - pbinom(1, 21, 0.02)` and `1 - pbinom(2, 21, 0.05)`, respectively. My desired output would be: `[1] 0.065348840 0.008125299` (row 1) and `[1] 0.28302816 0.08491751` (row 2). Perhaps you got this output? I'm not sure what I'm doing incorrectly. Thanks again.

Comment: I will try posting this as a new thread as I feel we have drifted from the original question at hand.

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass a for loop into a variable like that.  You could try this:

```
output=c()
for (i in 1:5){
output[i]=(1-pbinom(i,21,0.05))
}
```

Then if you type:

```
output
```

R will produce:

```
[1] 0.2830281552 0.0849175139 0.0188806334 0.0032403196 0.0004415266
```